# Overflow auto on unknown children height

Tags: css

I have an element (on which I know the width & height, I can't remove the height) with some elements inside. I've simplified it in the snippet so I just have a title (with unknown length) and a list.
I need the list (only the list, not the whole container) to be `overflow: auto` but I can't figure it out since I don't know its height and I can't use flexbox (IE9+ :/).

I want to avoid using JavaScript for this (I can do it in JavaScript but I really don't want a FOUC).

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 contenteditable>
    My long title that can be on multiple lines
  </h1>
  <ul>
    <li>a list</li>
    <li>of element</li>
    <li>that can</li>
    <li>be long</li>
    <li>that should</li>
    <li>overflow auto</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
    <li>bla</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: just remove the height on div

Comment: I can't, it's actually a position absolute element with top/bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my JS solution for now, I'd like to have it in CSS if possible but it's working in the meantime:

```
const height = container.clientHeight - list.offsetTop
list.style.height = height + 'px'
```

Comment: Wouldn't subtracting `clientHeight`s or `offsetHeight`s be easier?

Comment: Make sense, I've replace the BoundingRect (I was manipulating a lot of BBoxes that's why I did that) with `clientHeight` and `offsetTop`

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do it

First would be just remove the `height` prop on `div`.

If you don't want to do so.. you can either choose to cut `(overflow:hidden)` or scroll `overflow:scroll` the `list`

ie, you div styling can be:

```
div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll; /* or hidden */
}
```

or just

```
div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**EDIT**:If you dont want the whole container to `overflow` (as said in comments) just add `max-hight` to `ul`

your ul styling would be something like:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 100px; /*or anything you think appropriate */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

and rest of the css can be same as in OP.

Comment: I can't remove the height, it's actually a position absolute element with top/bottom, and I only want the list to be overflown, not the whole container.

Answer (score 0):

just add overflow-y: auto; to your container element

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  float: left;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 contenteditable>
    My long title that can be on multiple lines
  </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>a list</li>
      <li>of element</li>
      <li>that can</li>
      <li>be long</li>
      <li>that should</li>
      <li>overflow auto</li>
      <li>blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
      <li>bla</li>
      <li>bla</li>
      <li>bla</li>
      <li>bla</li>
    </ul>
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want only the list to overflow, not the whole container.

Comment: well how about that? Only thing is now the headline changes the height of the overall container.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the height of both dynamic, without something like JavaScript.

For one to overflow, it needs a reference. Why would the list overflow but not the header for example?

You can go set the list position to absolute, but then you need coordinates for top and bottom, which you won't have because in CSS you can't get that from other element (the header).

Without something like flex, you other option is JS I think.

You can render the header and list with visibility hidden (not display block, so their dimentions can be calculated), and remove that once you apply your JS for minimal FLOC effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use flexbox, use CSS tables:

- Set the height of the table
- Set `height: 0` to the title cell to make it be only as tall as required by its contents.
- Wrap the `ul` inside a table-row, which will take the remaining space left by the title.
- Take the `ul` out-of-flow (to avoid circular definitions) and make it have the same sizes as that wrapper.

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
#container > h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
#container > div {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}
#container ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 contenteditable>
    My long title that can be on multiple lines
  </h1>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>a list</li>
      <li>of element</li>
      <li>that can</li>
      <li>be long</li>
      <li>that should</li>
      <li>overflow auto</li>
      <li>bla</li>
      <li>bla</li>
      <li>bla</li>
      <li>bla</li>
      <li>bla</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```